# StaleElementReferenceException after 15 elements in image gallery

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I'm trying to get image links from my website, it has around 40 images and I'm using `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector` to get all the images to a list.

When I loop through this list and print id of these images, for the first 15 images it's working fine everything after that it throwing `StaleElementReferenceException`

I'm using `WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'image-list')))` for loading my image gallery.

How I can fix this `StaleElementReferenceException`

Thanks.

Comment: Is the gallery publicly accessible?

Comment: @QHarr - Sorry it's not publicly accessible

Comment: Can you post few lines of code how you are doing it.then OP might found what’s wrong in your code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the container holding the images loading them dynamically, so you have to use the below logic.

```
# load the images in the dynamic list container
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='image-list']//img)[last()]").location_once_scrolled_into_view
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='image-list']//img)[last()]").location_once_scrolled_into_view
time.sleep(1)
#get number of images
images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='image-list']//img")
# use the for loop
for imageNum in range(len(images)):
    # access the image here
    image = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='image-list']//img[)" + str(imageNum+1) + "]")
    # now you can use the image element (first scroll to element)
    image.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    # get the image link here
    print(image.get_attribute('src'))
```